# How to combine WHERE and HAVING in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

How do I write a query for MySQL that would filter out where total pay is less than zero.
I have tried different commands using 'HAVING' but I can't figure out the proper syntax.

This is my command:

```
SELECT tickets.idno, tickets.PAY, tickets.MATERIAL
FROM tickets
WHERE ( tickets.PAY <> 0  OR  tickets.MATERIAL <> 0 ) AND  tickets.DISTRICT = 'HO'  AND tickets.DATEPAID IS NULL  
ORDER BY tickets.NAME
```

with this result set:

```
HO0045  -140    0
HO2203  -45     0
HO2411  -5      0
HO2411  20      0
HO3448  -156    0
HO2519  2000    0
HO0075  -300    0
HO1669  -55     0
HO2666  -200    0
HO2666  -200    0
HO3447  -400    0
HO3447  400     0
```

This is result I get now, but it needs to eliminate those records where the total pay + total material for all rows for a given IDNO are less than zero.  For example; all the rows for HO2411 and HO2519 should appear but not the rest.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING` is meant to filter out whole groups, but to do that, you need to reduce the query with `GROUP BY`. But unfortunately you can't reverse the grouping operation after filtering groups.

So you have to do a subquery to filter the groups, then `JOIN` that result back to the table to find the rows with the corresponding idno:

```
SELECT t.idno, t.PAY, t.MATERIAL
FROM tickets AS t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT idno, SUM(PAY) AS PAY, SUM(MATERIAL) AS MATERIAL
  FROM tickets
  GROUP BY idno
  HAVING PAY + MATERIAL < 0
) AS total USING (idno)
WHERE t.DISTRICT = 'HO' AND t.DATEPAID IS NULL  
ORDER BY t.NAME;
```